# Static IP proxy for a Steam Server?

Tags: proxy, ip, steam, static-ip-address, garrys-mod

I've been developing a **Steam Game Server (Garry's Mod)** and have been wondering how I'd be able to get over the **issue** of a dynamic public IP. I'd like to host my server locally but my ISP do not allow static public IP's.

I might be completely wrong here - but would I be able to use a **proxy to bypass this?** Maybe one that I can tell my Steam Game Server to use...?

I've been attempting to search online, but there hasn't been much success in that regard. If you have any solutions for me other than renting a dedicated server, I'd love to hear them. Also: if you know any **proxy websites** that would allow the kind of thing I'm looking for if applicable would help greatly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this isn't as informative, this is my first post here.

Public IP's are assigned by your ISP, and is the IP that points to your router. I highly recommend reading Sylvain's answer [here.](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-check-if-my-internet-IP-address-is-static-or-dynamic)

You can always change ISP, but running a Server off your local machine is a bit hectic on performance as well. If you're running it off a dedicated machine, then electricity/ddos protection is quite costly as well.

If you don't want to switch ISP, I highly recommend shelling out to a local provider of game servers. You can get them extremely cheap, and it keeps your local machine (Hopefully) lag free, and keeps away electricity costs of running it overnight.

Otherwise, switching ISP is probably your only option, if you don't want to give players network lag and such.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Hey William, thank you for your answer.

Is there really no way to route a changing public IP through a static one using some other kind of service? The type of server I can host from my machine would cost me at least $30 a month if I tried through a dedicated server host.

Comment: I recommend contacting your ISP, depending on who it is, they might have a cheap add-on for a static IP. I'd personally mess around with router settings as a just in-case, but that's probably because I don't have enough experience in the topic. Also $30 a month is pricy for a server host, If you do some digging or learn to do a bit of linux jazz you can get them as little as $3-5 a month. Either way, keep me updated with your endeavours, gmod's a favourite game of mine :)

Comment: If you want, we can chat on discord about it, haha. - Nagrom#9235

Comment: Your discord doesn't work